# phpMyAdmin shows a dashboard but no tables on my fresh XAMPP install

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

[image: phpmyAdmin dashboard]

Hey,

I've installed a second instance of XAMPP and configured the ports to be unique and not conflict with the original XAMPP install that has default ports and settings.

phpMyAdmin has the dashboard shown in the image and seems broken

This second install is completely fresh, only changes to the defaults are as below.

Here's the configuration that I've used:

Apache port 8080, 444 for SSL
MySWL port 3307
Original XAMPP is in C:\xampp
Second install is in C:\xampp_8_1_12\

Second install:
mysql\bin\my.ini I set the server-id = 2
phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php I set the initial $i value to 1

I've checked that the PID in msqlId.exe matched the one shown on the XAMPP control panel.

The first install of XAMPP works as expected

I don't have much experience with server set up.

I was expecting to see the usual database list in phpMyAdmin dashboard. Instead I have the dashboard without databases as show in the image

Answer (score 0):

My solution has been a different approach. Instead of having two (or more) installs of XAMPP I am instead using one and [following this guide](https://neutrondev.com/multiple-php-versions-in-xampp/) to set up different PHP versions in the single install of XAMPP